# Как сделать inner join в TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Помогите переписать inner join в TypeOrm
Вот той код в sql синтаксисе:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM nodes as n
inner join public.validator as v
on v.id = "validatorId"
where wallet = '0x4A173026bc1145102820604a3C1B3Eca404ce85e'
```

Comment: из запроса не понятна связь между validator и nodes

Comment: https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#inner-and-left-joins